# Evaluate an expression for multiple values of the variable

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have a mathematical function, and in order to evaluate its value with multiple x values I would write something like this:

```
from sympy import *

x = 0
_function = x + ln(x)
print(_function.evalf(5))

x = 1
_function = x + ln(x)
print(_function.evalf(5))`
```

Is there a faster method to evaluate the same function with multiple x values while skipping that

```
_function = x + ln(x)
```

step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your question is  not really Sympy-specific, and you just want to declare a function in Python. It can be done in one line using lambda syntax:

```
f = lambda x: x+ln(x)
```

Now f(2) and f(5) return expected results.

Comment: It returns "function object has no attribute 'evalf'

Comment: There is no "evalf" in my answer.